# How to create a Search API block?

Tags: 8, blocks, search

I have a search view based on "Search API", I want to replace the default search block of the drupal core with a block "Search API".

1) How to modify the search block of the heart so that it uses search api instead ?

or

2) How to create a custom block /structure/block/block-content to use "Search API" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an exposed filter for the View page, probably based on the full text search field, and then set the filter form to show in a block.

All can be done from within the Views UI on the edit form for the search page.

Comment: Okay, but I can not put the text "Enter your search" in the text field (placeholder) and the images are not taken into account for the submit button.

Comment: Ok, so you have 2 new questions to ask...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "enter your search" you can use Better exposed filter module.(see https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)